# Add a version of file to a existing file version(ContentVersion)

Tags: contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I am trying to attach a versions of file with content Versions to a existing content version, i don't know how to do that... 
actually i arrive to insert file but some duplicate file is present and i don't want to delete the duplicate file just add a versions on it. 
let me show u my code :

```
    list<contentDocumentLink> ExistingContDocLink = [select contentDocumentId, contentDocument.title, contentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId 
                                         from contentDocumentLink 
                                         where LinkedEntityId =: projet.id
                                         AND contentDocument.title = :pdfName];

                                         System.debug('ExistingContDocLink  : ' + ExistingContDocLink);

            List<ContentVersion> listversion = [select contentDocumentId, contentDocument.title from ContentVersion where ContentDocument.title = :pdfName];                                    
    if(ExistingContDocLink.isEmpty()){
        // Il n'y a pas de doc, j'insère 
       //if ther're not documents
         fl.ContentLocation = 'S';
         fl.PathOnClient = pdfName;
         fl.Origin = 'H';
         fl.Title = pdfName;
         fl.VersionData = boddy;

         insert fl;
        System.debug('apres insertion : ' + fl.title);

    }else {
   //here there're some document: here i try to add a verions of my document and  add in existing document finded.
              System.debug('listversion avant ajout  ' + listversion );

               fl.ContentLocation = 'S';
           fl.PathOnClient = pdfName;
           fl.Origin = 'H';
        fl.Title = pdfName;
         fl.VersionData = boddy;

         listversion.add(fl);
        System.debug('listversion ' + listversion );



         //update listversion;
        //System.debug('apres update');
    }
```

Comment: actually i insert some document to the file folder, just i don't want to have some duplicate files, so i am looking for a methode where we can just add a version of existing file. like my first request, i searching if some document is existing and matches, first looop : if my file folder  is empty (with my request), i insert a new one, and the second loop... if is existing i am trying to attach a version of my document to a existing document... like a couple of versions document, i hope, i arrive to be clearly. Thanks

Comment: Please **[edit] your post** to describe your problem using words and *ask a question*.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<ContentVersion> listversion = [select contentDocumentId, contentDocument.title from ContentVersion where ContentDocument.title = :pdfName];                                     
    System.debug('listversion : ' + listversion);
    ContentVersion fl = new ContentVersion();

            fl.ContentLocation = 'S';
            fl.PathOnClient = pdfName;
            fl.Origin = 'H';
            fl.Title = pdfName;
            fl.VersionData = body;
        if (!listversion.isEmpty()){
        fl.ContentDocumentId= listversion[0].ContentDocumentId;
        }

   Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
   try{
           insert fl;
        if(listversion.isEmpty()){


        fl = [select ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where id =: fl.Id];

        ContentDocumentLink cl = new ContentDocumentLink(
        LinkedEntityId = idProjet,
        ContentDocumentId = fl.ContentDocumentId,
        ShareType = 'I'
        );
        insert cl;   
        }         
     } catch(Exception e) {
         Database.rollback(sp);

        System.debug(e.getMessage());          
        throw e;
     }
```